# How to do something to when using td+td to first td

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/tad564ys/28/

```
    var donotcountBye = true;

    var ByeWeek = function() {
        var result = "";
        if(donotcountBye) {
            result = result + "td.new+td:contains('Bye')";
        }
        return result;
    }

$(ByeWeek()).css('background', 'green');
```

How can i do something to the td.new when using td.new+td

HTML

```
<table>
<tr><td class="new">TEXT</td><td>Bye</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ByeWeek` is a function, you need to call it with the parenthesis `()`:

```
$(ByeWeek()).css('background', 'green');
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tad564ys/22/

**EDIT:**

You can use `.prev()`, like this:

```
$(ByeWeek()).prev().css('background', 'green');
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tad564ys/34/